"Nginx Path-Based Routing Issue: Login Fails at /cs/ Path on HTTPS"
I’m currently configuring Nginx for path-based routing, and I've run into an issue where logging in to my application works when accessed via a specific URL, but fails when accessed through another URL with a different base path.
Problem:
When I access the application at http://example-ip1:16200/cs/, the login works as expected.
However, when accessing the application at https://wcc.rapidhr.com/cs/, I am unable to log in.
Nginx Configuration:
Here is my default.conf configuration for Nginx:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name wcc.rapidhr.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    # Path-based routing
    location /wcc/ {
        proxy_pass http://example-ip2:16225/wcc/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://wcc.rapidhr.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, Authorization';
    }

    location /cs/ {
        proxy_pass http://example-ip1:16200/cs/;
        proxy_cookie_path /cs/ /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    }

    # Additional location blocks for other paths...

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

Details:
Other location blocks (like /wcc/, etc.) work fine.
The /cs/ path seems to have issues with login when accessed through the domain URL, but not when accessed directly via IP and port.
I’ve set proxy_cookie_path for /cs/, which I thought might be necessary, but it doesn’t resolve the issue.
What I’ve Tried:
Checked Nginx logs for errors or warnings.
Verified that all paths and endpoints are correctly mapped.
Ensured that the SSL certificates are correctly set up.
Questions:

Could there be an issue with how proxy_pass is handling the /cs/ path?
Is there something specific I might be missing in the Nginx configuration that affects login functionality?
Are there any additional settings or debugging steps I should consider?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated

